# Enable non-signed references in SSIS Task Script

Tags: reference, ssis, .net-assembly, strongname, script-task

As far as i Know SSIS references has to be strong name (signed). The question is: Can I change SSIS preferences to allow using references to unsigned assembly ? 
Regards, Tom

Comment: I haven't heard of anyone doing it. That's not to say it's impossible, mind you

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not just give it a strong name?